# Cannot send JSON as request body to Spring Controller

Tags: java, json, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

**STEP 1:** Ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "url",
  type: "POST",
  dataType: 'json',
  data:{
    'id': '1',
    'type': 'BOOK_VIEWED',
    'access_token': response.response.access_token
  },
  crossDomain: true,
  success: function() { }
});
```

**STEP 2.** Get parameter from request before executing Spring Controller method; here are two variants:

- **Variant 1:** If I send the ajax request with `content-type: json` in the header, this will *not* work; otherwise it will:

```
    String token = request.getParameter(HEADER_SECURITY_TOKEN);
```

- **Variant 2:** If I set `content-type: json` in the header, this will work:

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        sb.append(line).append('\n');
```

**STEP 3.** The Spring Controller `bookOpened` method should be executed:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/event",
                    method = RequestMethod.POST,
                        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public void bookOpened(@RequestBody PostEvent postEvent, HttpServletRequest request) {
    // ..
}
```

When attempting to run, the `bookOpened` method is not executed and a `415(unsupported media type) Exception` is thrown. If the method signature is changed to accept only the: `HttpServletRequest request` parameter (without the `@RequestBody` parameter), it will work; but this is not a viable solution for me.

**The primary problems:**

- In Step 2, I would like to get a parameter from the request.
- In Step 3, I would like to include the `@RequestBody` parameter, not just a `HttpServletRequest` parameter.

Comment: Did you include dependencies: `jackson-core` and `jackson-databin` in you project?

Comment: And how do you going to get params **before** controller? With interceptor, or any other way?

Answer (score 0):

**STEP 3**

To force message converter process you request, you have to specify it's content- type. It must be `application/json`. In `data` parameter of request you have to send `String`, but not `array`. So, your request could look as following:

```
var post = {};
post['id']=1;
post['type']='BOOK_VIEWED';
post['access_token']=response.response.access_token;

$.ajax({
       url: 'url',
       type: 'post',
       contentType : 'application/json',
       dataType:'json',
       data:JSON.stringify(post)
   })
   success: function() { ... }
})
```

Also, to include json message converter into your project you have declare some dependencies. If you have not already done it, include this dependencies into your `pom`:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
   <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
   <version>2.4.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
   <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
   <version>2.4.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

**STEP 2**

Because client sends request just once, you can read body of request *just once*. So, never use `request.getReader()`, except when you use it in `HttpMessageConverter` implementation. To get value from request, you could send it as request parameter(query). In your case, to add parameters to url, you have compose url-string manually:

```
...

$.ajax({
       url: 'url?acces_token='+encodeURIComponent(response.response.access_token),
       type: 'post',
       contentType : 'application/json',
       dataType:'json',
       data:JSON.stringify(post)
   })
   success: function() { ... }
})
```

After that, you can get request parameter with well known for you way:

```
String token = URLDecoder.decode(request.getParameter('acces_token'), "utf-8");
```

Not, that you have encode token before pass it as url parameter and decode it again, when you get it on server side.

Hope, this will be helpful.